# Can't access .smbcredentials after upgrade to Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, samba, fstab

I have a simple Puppylinux server sharing two folders over Samba. The LAN has about 16 other PCs with a very wide variety of OSes of varying ages.

The Ubuntu Studio PC auto-mounts the shared folders on boot, using fstab entries. A smbcredentials file is used, with permissions 600.

But since upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, I receive the following error:-

mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

I understand this might be a catchall error caused by the fstab entry. Which is:-

//192.168.1.112/vol2 /home/dave/vol1 cifs users,exec,dev,suid,rw,credentials=/.smbcredentials,noperm,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0,acl, 0 0

dmesg returns:-
[70672.547621] CIFS: VFS: bad security option: ntlm

So I wonder if ntlm has been deprecated in 22.04, disabled by default, or given a different name.

If so, how can it be re-enabled? And is it possible to prevent future Ubuntu version upgrades from repeating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mount.cifs is controlled by the Linux kernel.

The kernel you are using in Ubuntu 22.04 has ntlm removed as an option.

By default cifs negotiates with the server to determine the highest smb dialect ( vers ) to use starting with SMB2.1 all the way up to SMB 3.X

Also by default cifs uses sec=ntlmssp which is many levels above the old ntlm value.

Answer (score 0):

Removing sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 from the fstab entry works, but this is replacing deprecated password encryption with no password encryption.

sec=krb5 and sec=sys break it, but replacing sec=ntlm with sec=ntlmssp in the fstab entry works per Morbius' advice

Comment: Please don't post follow-up questions as answers. If you have solved your problem, it's fine to post the solution as an answer, but ask a new question for the followups. This isn't a forum.

Comment: thank you + have amended in line with this